# SharePoint 2016 multiple web app in port 80

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, web-application

Environment SharePoint 2016

1. I am creating a new web application on the port 80 where we already
   have two different web apps.
2. I have a DNS created for my web front server IP address to point to this dns.
3. I am giving the host header name "testingdev.dot.com" and creating the web app with    http://testingdev.dot.com as default zone
4. I am then extending this web app to port 443 and giving host header name "testingdev.dot.com"
   with SSL selected and selecting zone as custom
5. In AAM i am editing the public url making custom zone as default and default zone as
   custom
6. In web front end server i have set the bindings for 443 site and added cert to it
7. when I am trying to access 443 site with https://testingdev.dot.com it opens with out any issue
8. But when I try to open the site without giving http or https directly testingdev.dot.com it is taking to other exising web application "eg: 'https://othertestingdev.dot.com'
9. can some one suggest where am exactly going wrong here. its been a week and I am still unable to figure out where am doing wrong on this.

Comment: Do you have the URL rewrite module installed? If so, has a rule already been configured to redirect all other subdomains to the incorrect subdomain?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using HTTP at all and don't just use SSL-only?

Comment: Hi @Callum Crowley I do have url rewrite but I have seen that it will cause search and user profile issues . And moreover my other web apps which follow same scenario working fine except this one.thank you

Comment: Hi @trevor Seward we should be able to access the site internal users as well .

Comment: There's no reason you need to use HTTP for internal users to access it. You can and should only be using HTTPS.

Comment: Hi Trevor so are you saying i dont need to extend the web application created on port 80?